# iOS App Deployment options for enterprise apps

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store, enterprise

Here is my situation (please keep in mind that I am fairly new to iOS apps and the different ways we can deploy them)

We are building an iOS app that works against a customers server.  We have many customers.  Let's assume that we deploy version 1 of the app and distribute it to all our customers.  Now let's say that one of our customers has found a crucial bug that needs to be fixed.  This bug affects only a couple customers because of the workflows/steps they are taking.  The bug exists for the other customers but doesn't affect them.  Let's say that this bug requires a fix on the client-side and the server-side as well and lets assume that version 2 of this app will ONLY work if the server-side has the bug fix.

The dilemma here is that we want a way to push version 2 of the app to only the customers who have the server-side bug fix.  The reason for this is because we may not have full access to all of our customer's server on a given time/date and we don't want to delay a bug fix release until we have updated everyone's webservice.

So basically what we need is a way to control which customer(s) gets what app update.  We want a way to say "Ok lets push version 2 to Customer 1 today.  And lets push version 2 to Customer 2 a week from now".

Is there any such way to do this?  This is a crucial requirement of our project.

Thanks,
Cameron

Comment: You should include backward compatibility checks in your client code so that it works with the available server. For example, if you make a breaking change in a RESTful API then the endpoint should change to a new version. Then your client can check for the existence of the new api endpoint and if it gets a 404 it can fall back to the older endpoint. You could even include an unversioned endpoint on your server that provided the endpoints available on that server, so the first thing a client can do is check the server version.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very interesting question. To be honest I am not fully aware if this can be achieved, but if it could be possible, then the only way it could be developed would be by deploying your app as a B2B (Business to Business app) which would allow you to better customize your app but also require your customers to sign up to the Apple Volume Purchase pfrogam.

You can find more details here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Hope this helped!

Best regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need Mobile Application Management or Mobile Device Management:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_management

https://medium.com/swlh/mobile-device-management-mdm-for-ios-60448313dafb

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management